# What is the best approach to execute a piece of code only at the end of a series of events?

Tags: c#

I subscribed to an Event using a 3rdParty API which, in some cases, is fired a hundred times within a second. The piece of code I'm executing when the Event is called runs quickly, but if the event is fired a hundred times in a second it can be very slow. The piece of code only updates the UI so it is enough to execute it after the "last" event is fired. I said "last" because the event might be fired again 5 seconds later but I don't want to wait for that.

So let's say if another event is not fired 50 milliseconds after the previous one then we need to execute the piece of code.

My first approach was, of course, using a Timer. However using a Timer for such tasks is not recommended in my project. What other ways do you know to accomplish this programming task?

The project is written in C#.
I cannot use other libraries for this task. Unfortunately it's the limitation of the project. I have to stick with .NET Framework.

Comment: Just throwing an idea at you, but take a look at Reactive Extension Throttling

Comment: Sounds like a good case for Reactive Extensions (Rx): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: "However using a Timer for such tasks is not recommended in my project". Why not?

Comment: Rx looks very promising! However, I forgot to mention, that I cannot use other libraries for this task. Unfortunately it's the limitation of the project I was assigned to. I have to stick with .NET Framework.

Comment: @Tarik it is not recommended by the project architects. Earlier there were other scenarios a Timer was used for such task. It figured out it has hidden issues in a huge project.

Comment: Following this principle, if some buggy piece of code happens to use component X, shall we stop using component X?

Answer (score 1):

Each time the event is fired, store the current time. The next time the event is fired compare the current time with the previous time. If it is above some threshold execute your logic.

Comment: This is not a good approach. Let's say 100 events are fired every 10 milliseconds and after 1 minute another 100 events are fired. If the threshold is 50 ms the piece of code will be executed only when the first event is fired in the second group, which is not good.

Comment: So what's the difference if you execute it for the first or the last event in a group?

Comment: Well, just think about it. The second series of events might be fired soon, but might be fired hours later. You wouldn't want to wait for an hour to have an updated UI with the data received in the first series. That's a difference.

Comment: In that case, you need to generate an event somehow. The use of a timer seems unescapable.